# How to make apprtc demo sample video chat to be fast in native android

Tags: java, android, webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

I have done some research on webrtc then i found apprtc demo sample application which is have taken from https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo in android. I have implemented this but this app take time in offering a call.It follow these step

1) It first request to webrtc server and then a json return from server.
2) In program it collect 4 ice url by hitting the turn server url and save it in linkedlist.
3) Then it send offer by appending roomid , clientid and message in webrtc server url which return success.

4) it open it socket for communication in future.

5) Now it hit the server four time with ice server which return candidate in
  json formate.

6)Now I have taken our own server which send call to other person mobile.

7) Then other person accept the request and make a post on webrtc server url
  and json return from it.

8) Now the answer is created and hit the socket to open.

9) The Icecandidate is accepted by the person and send that icecandidate to other person.

The webrtc server which i have taken is Google App Engine written in python. In this i don't know how to notify other person to pick call. Here I have used other server to notify other person for call.

After following these steps the communication start. Is there any way to make this step less so that communication can become fast.

Also I have taken my own server to make a call to other person. I don't know python that's why it difficult for me to edit the server so that it will help in communication without taking help of other server.